# Need help spotting potential misunderstanding and improper practice of Python fundamentals

Tags: python, class, object, refactoring

I'm in need of constructive criticism & advice on how I structure my code, especially with the classes.

Below is a lottery game I wrote where player will guess a number between 1 to X with a total of Y tries, each wins = $100 in prize (The prize don't stack when you replay the game).

```
import random

max_attempts = 5
max_answer = 5 
prize = 100

class Count:
    win_count = 0

class Answer:
    def generate_answer():
        return random.randint(1, max_answer)

class Sequence: 
    def sequence(n):
        if n >= 4:
            return f"{n}th"
        else:
            return f"{n}{'st' if n == 1 else 'nd' if n == 2 else 'rd'}"
    
def play_game():
    for attempts in range(1, (max_attempts + 1)):
        while True:
            choose_guess = (input(f"\nGuess a number in the range of 1 to {max_answer} ({Sequence.sequence(attempts)} Attempt): "))
            try:
                guess_num = int(choose_guess)
                answer = Answer.generate_answer()
                if guess_num == answer:
                    Count.win_count += 1
                    print(
                        f"[CORRECT! The answer is {answer}! You win ${prize}!]\n")
                elif guess_num > max_answer or guess_num < 1:
                    print(f"[The number must be in the range of 1 to {max_answer}]\n")
                else:
                    print(f"[INCORRECT! The answer is {answer}]\n")
                break

            except ValueError:
                print(
                    f"[Value Error! Please enter an integer in the range of 1 to {max_answer}]\n")
            break
                
    total_prize = Count.win_count * prize
    print(f"▶ [Total win(s): {Count.win_count} / Prize: ${total_prize}]\n\n")
    choose_play()

def choose_play():
    play = input("\nPlay Game? Y/N: ")
    if play.upper() == "Y":
        play_game()
    elif play.upper() == "N":
        print("\nHave a nice day!") 
    else:
        print("\nUnknown Input")
        choose_play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    choose_play()
```

The code works for me and doesn't really show any bugs in my testings, but I can't help but feel like I'm doing something wrong. For example the win_count = 0 being a class, which works for me but only as a class, neither as a global variable nor as a function worked but I don't understand why.

Chances are I'm probably misusing or confusing something fundamental about Python. Is there a way to write this code in a much more professional and "proper" way? I'm a self taught and sometimes I get too comfortable when things work, I wish to further examine & review the way I code and how I approach Python, however simple or beginner level the code may seem.

Comment: Using a good IDE (e.g., Visual Studio Code with Pylance) would help you to visualise numerous problems with your code.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Visual Studio Code with Pylance and it doesn't show any problems, however I wish to further review my code to hone my thought process and check if I perhaps misunderstood or confuse something that could be working right now but might cause issues later on. (I'm not a big fan of ''If it works it works'')

Comment: I don't know what version of VSCode/Pylance you're using but my versions highlight [potential] problems with your Sequence class. You don't really need a class here - you just need a function. If you insist on wrapping it in a class then you should decorate it as @staticmethod. https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this

Comment: Why are you using classes? They seem rather out of place. Everything you have as a class can simply be a function/variable/global variable. Using while loop inside the for loop is also overkill for this case. The same can be accomplished by a single while loop. I will post an answer of refactored version but my guess is the question will get blocked before I can do that. try stack exchange code review instead: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
the question will be more fitting there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will move this topic to stackexchange instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways how the code can be improved hence there is no single correct answer.

Here is a version that will use more appropriate tools for the task you are trying to solve:

```
import random

MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5
MAX_ANSWER = 5
PRIZE = 100


def sequence(n):
    if n >= 4:
        return f"{n}th"
    else:
        return f"{n}{'st' if n == 1 else 'nd' if n == 2 else 'rd'}"


def play_game():
    win_count = 0
    attempts = 0
    while attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS:
        choose_guess = input(f"\nGuess a number in the range of 1 to {MAX_ANSWER} ({sequence(attempts)} Attempt): ")
        try:
            guess_num = int(choose_guess)
            answer = random.randint(1, MAX_ANSWER)
            if guess_num == answer:
                win_count += 1
                print(
                    f"[CORRECT! The answer is {answer}! You win ${PRIZE}!]\n")
                attempts += 1
            elif guess_num > MAX_ANSWER or guess_num < 1:
                print(f"[The number must be in the range of 1 to {MAX_ANSWER}]\n")
            else:
                print(f"[INCORRECT! The answer is {answer}]\n")
                attempts += 1

        except ValueError:
            print(f"[Value Error! Please enter an integer in the range of 1 to {MAX_ANSWER}]\n")

    total_prize = win_count * PRIZE
    print(f"▶ [Total win(s): {win_count} / Prize: ${total_prize}]\n\n")
    choose_play()


def choose_play():
    play = input("\nPlay Game? Y/N: ")
    if play.upper() == "Y":
        play_game()
    elif play.upper() == "N":
        print("\nHave a nice day!")
    else:
        print("\nUnknown Input")
        choose_play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    choose_play()
```

- No need to use Classes. They are for a very different use case. If you really need to use Classes then try to think of a single game attempt/round as a class since that is the repeating part that can be abstracted.
- Look into global and local variables and when they should be used. For example, `attempts` does not need to be global variable because it is used by only one function. It can be a variable inside that function. In general, if you can, try to avoid Global variables.
- While loop inside the for loop was unnecessary. Same can be accomplished with a single while loop that would use number of attempts as a break condition. Note that attempts are only counted if the input was valid.

Things you can look into further:

- @DarkKnight is rightly concerned about the recursion in choose_play() function. Based on other functionality you plan to implement think about possible ways of replacing it. Mistakes in recursive function multiply well recursively :) and its very hard to debug. Not mentioning the fact that you can end up in endless recursion...
- Use smaller Try/Except. Think about what exactly do you expect to go wrong and try to catch that specific line. Right now all ValueError's within that code block are going to be caught with your except. It can result in confusion and make debugging very difficult.

As I already mentioned: [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) will be a more appropriate place to place this question.

Happy coding!

Comment: Are you happy with the recursion in your *choose_play()* function?

Comment: I'm not sure if that counts as a recrusion but the purpose for that is if you enter anything else but Y or N in the "Play game? '' input it will just tell you ''Unknown Input'' and then ask again if you want to play. Only when you enter N will the whole thing stop.

Comment: Thank you so very much @Geom that was incredibly helpful, it seems like I:  
1. Don't understand the purpose of Python Classes or when to use them
2. Overengineered the code with unnecessary for loop outside of a while loop
3. Should pay more attention to global and local variables and when they should be used

Comment: @DarkKnight is rightly concerned about the recursion. You already have the structures in your code that can replace it. Can you find them?

Comment: @Geom I used a while loop inside the choose_play() function and then removed the choose_play() function from the bottom of play_game() function to avoid calling it again when entered N.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what i had in mind! Good job!